# How to make the TCP Server run till it is stopped

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

Sample https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server is great to build a TCP Server application. Its simple and runs on JVM. It does not need any Application Server.

Sample uses command line input to run the program. I want the server to accept data only from the Socket port and not through the command line. If I remove the command line input, main thread is finishing and the program no longer accepts input from the port. I have to keep the main thread running all the time.

I am thinking some thing like this:

```
    boolean isGatewayStopped = false;
    while (!isGatewayStopped) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            isGatewayStopped = getGatewayStatus();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have two questions:

1. is there a clean way of making the Main thread continue to run?
2. How to know that Gateway is stopped? If the user sends TCP data as "quit" then gateway can be stopped. is there any way to know that gateway is stopped?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hit 'Enter' to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
}
```

You start the `ApplicationContext` and wait for the stop from the console input.

**EDIT**

For the case when you would like to stop program via an event in the application, you can register `ApplicationListener` and wait on the barrier before existing from the `main`:

```
CountDownLatch exitLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
ctx.addApplicationListener(ContextClosedEvent e -> exitLatch.countDown())
exitLatch.await();
```

Now you should just come up with some logic in your application to call `ctx.stop()` there.

Comment: I do not want to take input from command line because its a server. is there any utility in spring that can start daemon thread and poll for the status of gateway?

Comment: See an EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Thats perfect Artem. quick question:
Refer to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/monitoring for using control-channel. 

Message<String> operation = MessageBuilder.withPayload("@integrationMBeanExporter.stopActiveComponents(false, 20000)").build();

if (this.exporter != null) {
 this.controlBusChannel.send(operation);
}

if I send stopActiveComponents() using control-channel, will it send ContextClosedEvent ?

Comment: M-m-m. You really have to call `AplicationContext.close()` somehow in your code. And yes, some your component with `@ManagedOperation` can be called from `control-bus` for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can call wait() on the gateway thread from the main thread to make the main thread wait until gateway thread finishes. You'll need to call the notify() from gateway thread (when it should stop) to indicate that it's finished and waiting threads should proceed to run (in this case main will run and exit). An example can be [found here](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/).

Or else (a different solution for a very simple app), you can try something like following to read data from a main method and stop the program when the data read is equal to a command to stop the program:

```
class Server
{
   static Executor pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
      while (true)
      {
         final Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
         Runnable r = new Runnable()
                      {
                         @Override
                         public void run()
                         {
                            // read data from socket 's' here
                            // call System.exit() if command is to stop.
                         }
                      };
         pool.execute(r);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Reading of the socket data is handled by spring integration, hence System.exit() can not be called. Spring integration already has a port open to read data. I do not want to open another port like 9000 just to close the system.